# sql.js (sql-wasm.js) Not Working in Javascript Using Django

Tags: javascript, sql, django

I'm trying to use sql.js(sql-wasm.js) in javascript Using Django .But I got the same error:

```
TypeError: initSqlJs(...).then is not a function
```

Special Thanks To your answers

```html
 <p id="output">Output is here..</p>

 {% block js %}

  <script src="{% static 'js/require.js' %}">
</script>
 
<script>

  var baseUrl = "{% static 'js/sql.js/dist' %}";
  require.config({
    baseUrl: baseUrl
  });
   
  require(['sql-wasm'], function success(initSqlJs) {
     alert(typeof initSqlJs);       //output: 'function'
     
     var config = {
        locateFile:  filename => '${baseUrl}/${filename}' 
        // locateFile: filename=>  "{% static '${baseUrl}/${filename}' %}"
      } 
    
     initSqlJs(config).then(function (SQL) {
        var db = new SQL.Database();
         db.run("CREATE TABLE test (id INT, name TEXT);");
         db.run("INSERT INTO  test VALUES(1, 'Jacob');");
         var result = db.exec("SELECT * FROM test;");
         document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
      });
 });
    
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally , I got the correct answer after I have tried again and again.

Use ` instead of   '    .

`` locateFile:  filename => `${baseUrl}/${filename}` ``